# Issue when preprocessing text with Ktrain and DistilBERT

Tags: python, keras, transformer-model, bert-language-model, distilbert

Following the example notebook here:

https://github.com/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/examples/text/20newsgroup-distilbert.ipynb

At STEP 1: Preprocess Data, I run into the errors listed below. When I do exactly the same in a Colab notebook, it works. What am I missing on my machine? I **am** able to run this with BERT, DistilBERT causes problems.

```
trn, val, preproc = text.texts_from_array(x_train=x_train, y_train=y_train,
                                      x_test=x_test, y_test=y_test,
                                      class_names=class_names,
                                      preprocess_mode='distilbert',
                                      maxlen=350)
```

causes:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-142-ff3842c91276> in <module>
      3                                           class_names=class_names,
      4                                           preprocess_mode='distilbert',
----> 5                                           maxlen=350)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ktrain/text/data.py in texts_from_array(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, class_names, max_features, maxlen, val_pct, ngram_range, preprocess_mode, lang, random_state, verbose)
    337                            classes = class_names,
    338                            lang=lang, ngram_range=ngram_range)
--> 339     trn = preproc.preprocess_train(x_train, y_train, verbose=verbose)
    340     val = preproc.preprocess_test(x_test,  y_test, verbose=verbose)
    341     return (trn, val, preproc)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ktrain/text/preprocessor.py in preprocess_train(self, texts, y, mode, verbose)
    766                                       pad_on_left=bool(self.name in ['xlnet']),
    767                                       pad_token=self.tok.convert_tokens_to_ids([self.tok.pad_token][0]),
--> 768                                       pad_token_segment_id=4 if self.name in ['xlnet'] else 0)
    769         self.set_multilabel(dataset, mode)
    770         return dataset

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ktrain/text/preprocessor.py in hf_convert_examples(texts, y, tokenizer, max_length, pad_on_left, pad_token, pad_token_segment_id, mask_padding_with_zero)
    280                                           pad_token=pad_token,
    281                                           pad_token_segment_id=pad_token_segment_id,
--> 282                                           mask_padding_with_zero=mask_padding_with_zero)
    283             features_list.append(features)
    284             labels.append(y[idx] if y is not None else None)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ktrain/text/preprocessor.py in hf_convert_example(text, tokenizer, max_length, pad_on_left, pad_token, pad_token_segment_id, mask_padding_with_zero)
    206         max_length=max_length,
    207     )
--> 208     input_ids, token_type_ids = inputs["input_ids"], inputs["token_type_ids"]
    209 
    210     # The mask has 1 for real tokens and 0 for padding tokens. Only real

KeyError: 'token_type_ids'
```

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: My guess is that you have a different version of ktrain or something else. Run `pip list` to list versions of the relevant packages.

Comment: I JUST discovered this before reading your comment @Jindřich. Works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as mentioned by Jindřich, it was a version issue. Updating solved the problem. The error message was somewhat misleading...